# How to find that the estimator is biased if for random sample a distribution is given as normal.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation

Given random sample $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ with the distribution $$f(x|\theta) = \left \{ \begin{aligned} e^{-(x-\theta)}, \ \ 0 < x < \theta \\ 0, \text{ otherwise.} \end{aligned} \right.  $$

where $\theta \in (-\infty, \infty).$ Show that the estimator $\theta_1 = \min\left\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \right\} $ is unbiased.

So, I don't even know where to start, should I randomly generate a minimum for a large amount of normally distributed data and then compare it to the minimum of a sample consisting some arbitrary number of variables? I need to find a solution for the problem in R and I cannot even imagine how to do this.

Comment: why do you think $e^{-(x-\theta)}, \ \ 0 < x < \theta$ is a density function?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ with the distribution

$$f(x|\theta) = \left \{ \begin{aligned} e^{-(x-\theta)}, \ \  \theta <x \\ 0, \text{ otherwise.} \end{aligned} \right.  $$
since in that case $f$ is a density function.

define $Y=\min (X_1,\cdots X_n) $

$$F_Y(y)=1-P(Y>y)=1-P(X_1>y,\cdots, X_n>y)=1-e^{-n(y-\theta)}$$
so

$$f_Y(y)=ne^{-n(y-\theta)} \hspace{1cm} \theta < y$$

so $E(Y)=\theta + \frac{1}{n}$.

so $Y$ is baised. By a simple simulation in R we show $Y$ is biased (as you asked).

we do this step $k$ times:

1) draw $n$ independent random sample $(X_1,\cdots X_n)\sim f_X$

2)calculate $Y_k=\min(X_1,\cdots X_n)$

then we have $k$ of $Y_k$. calculate mean of this $Y_k$ and it is done.

```
 theta<-5
 n<-10
 sim<-200
 Ymin<-c()
 for(k in 1:sim){
 set.seed(k)
 x<-rexp(n,1)+theta
 Ymin[k]<-min(x)
 }
 mean(Ymin);theta+1/n
 #[1] 5.094421   [1] 5.1
```

Comment: Can you explain, why did you add to the random deviate the theta? Why did you choose theta to be 5? Also why did you chose rate to be equal to 1?

Comment: It showed   for $\theta=5$ and $\lambda=1$(the exponential distribution parameter)  the estimator $Min(X_i)$ is biased  .  I choose them arbitrary, since if the estimator is unbaised, it must be unbaised for all value of parameters. on the other hands ,$\forall \theta$ $E_{\theta}(T)=\theta$. so I choose a $\theta$ and simulate form the distribution to check unbaisedness

Comment: this distribution is shifted exponential https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/130549/11/11_chapter%205.pdf . on the other hand, if $X\sim E(1)$ so $X+\theta$ is the distribution of above.

Comment: How did get from $f_Y (\theta) $ to $E(Y)$?

Comment: Also, I don't het why is cumulative function $F_Y = 1 - P(Y>y)$?

Comment: @user, "How did get from $f_Y(y)$ to $E(Y)$?", see https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/130549/11/11_chapter%205.pdf , part 5.5  , for the detail. Also $Y-\theta \sim $ Exponential

Comment: For the last question, Note $F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=1-P(Y>y)$